# Does every fraction $ > 1$ occur as $\sigma(n)/n$ for some $n$?

Tags: number-theory

Here $\sigma$ is the sum of divisor function, so $\sigma(2)/2 = 3/2, \sigma(6)/6 = 2$, $\sigma(24)/24 = 5/2$, $\sigma(11)/11 = 12/11$ etc.

I found it hard to find information on these fractions by googling, not in the least because typing $\sigma$ into google will give you tons of links about $\Sigma$.

I imagine there is either an elementary argument why the answer is 'no' or it is a well known open problem, but I couldn't find evidence for either option, so all help is welcome.

Comment: Fascinating question!

Comment: start with this... note that I do not know of any discussion of what values happen. I suggest starting with trying to get all numbers, say, below 2 that have fixed small denominator, such as 4/3, 5/3, then 5/4, 7/4, then 6/5, 7/5, 8/5, 9/5 and so on. Getting your ration large is quite restrictive, it would make it difficult to find anything. http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/ramanujanNR.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can study those fractions by using this formula to compute $\sigma(n)$ : if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ is the writing of $n$ as a product of powers of primes, then
$$\sigma(n)=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^{\alpha_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}$$
so
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^{\alpha_i+1}-1}{p_i^{\alpha_i+1}-p_i^{\alpha_i}}$$
Now does this cover every fraction greater than $1$, I just don't know.

One start for your researches : [Divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).

Comment: see http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/  and then http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html  His name and that of his student, G. Robin, are on some of the most prominent publications about the sum of divisors function. However, they usually are talking about finding especially large values of some number theoretic function.